# How to apply css, after Jquery adds a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a jquery accordion as following:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
     $("#accordion").accordion();
    }
</script>

<style>
.ui-accordion-content{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
}
</style>
```

JQuery creates a `div.ui-accordion-content` and applies the styles from `jquery-ui.css` to it.
Unfortunately my own css from the style tags is not applied.

Why?

Comment: Do you need the jquery-ui.css? Maybe just remove it? I never use that when using the standard jquery accordion.

Comment: Using `!important` in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come... - http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Here is another point of view: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-dev/css-important.shtml.

Comment: @VisioN sorry! WE CAN'T FIND THE PAGE YOU'RE AFTER...

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Strange. Here is the shorten link: http://bit.ly/74aQU0. It should work.

Comment: @VisioN That page illustrates why you should **not** use it in this scenario. It's a lazy fix that a proper parent selector fixes.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame You think that digging into tons of CSS rules, JS code, that alters inline styles, is better when you do fast changes?

Comment: @VisioN I cracked open the single Stylesheet the OP posted, found the only reference to that class and viola. Seriously dude, homework.

Comment: Sorry I turned your simple question into a kerfuffle. I just think using `!important` for a quick fix is dangerous and makes coding way harder than it has to be later down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The correct approach*

You need to understand CSS precendence, read up on it http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/.

Using this your code would be updated to the following:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Since it is defined exactly the same as in the linked jquery ui css and after it in the DOM it will therefor have precedence.

*The quick and dirty fix*

Fix by adding `!important` to your own style like this:

```
.ui-accordion-content{
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thats why I added the link to precedence and inheritance first. Most people here though are lazy and will always take the easy fix instead of actually learning the WHY. :/

Comment: Agreed, so why not demonstrate the best way and not only the easy fix? +1 if you do.

Comment: In hindsight I agree, I was not answering it properly. My answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules):

```
.ui-accordion-content {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come... http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Well, I don't really agree. Sometimes it is useful, especially when you need a fast result. By all means this is *one option*.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame. HA?! `!important` means it's **important** not _you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy_. Funny isn't it? Why did the css designers choose that name for this attribute???

Answer (score 0):

Download the jquery-ui.css, change the relevant style rules inside it and use that one instead of the public version.

OR

Try using !important after your css rules, like:

margin:0!important;

Comment: Using `!important` in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come... http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/